# I can't create a list of pictureboxes, index outside the bounds of the array C#

Tags: c#

I need to make some "sort of game" with animations in C#. So I need to create new pictureBoxes at the press of a button, and I tried to make it work with a list but there is something I miss.
Index outside the bounds of the array, I need to set the length of the pictureBoxList that's what the error tells me, but it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>(10);
    int ID = 0;

    private void buttonAddEnemy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ID++;
          pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + ID, true)[0]);
          pictureBoxList[ID].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 90);
          pictureBoxList[ID].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy";
          pictureBoxList[ID].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
          pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Enemy;
          pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
          pictureBoxList[ID].BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see any code of creating a PictureBox.

Comment: After ID++ you are indexing the element at position 1 but there is no element there. The first element added is at index 0

Comment: do the ID++ after you set the pictureBoxList[ID] properties

Comment: There is no element at index  at position 1, You add element that default added at position 0 and you just ID++ so you list index become is 1 but there is no element at 1. so do ID++ after end.

Comment: Do it in three steps so you do make stupid mistakes.  1) PictureBox newPictureBox = (PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + ID, true)[0]; 2)  pictureBoxList.Add(newPictureBox); 3) newPictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 90);

Comment: You cannot assume that Controls.Find() will find anything.  Blindly indexing with [0] is going to blow like this.  You'll need to get ahead by actually creating the control (new PictureBox()) and setting its Name property.

Comment: @HansPassant the error is bounds of array, the function would return null then it would be object reference error

Comment: [No](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,14897).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>(10);
    int ID = 0;
    int position = 0;
    private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ID++;
        pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + ID, true)[0]);
        pictureBoxList[position].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 90);
        pictureBoxList[position].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy";
        pictureBoxList[position].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
        pictureBoxList[position].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Enemy;
        pictureBoxList[position].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        pictureBoxList[position].BringToFront();
        position++;



    }
```

Comment: My code is working fine because pictureBox1 is control id name so we cant use ID as 1 for added pictureBoxList which dont have element at 1 position.

Answer (score -1):

First `List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>(10);` that 10 is the max length of the List its not filled with pictureboxes.So when you first click the button your id is 1 when you have only one element so it obviusly gives and excepetion.
It should be

```
pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + ID+1/* If your picture box is called pictureBOx1 and not pictureBox0 */, true)[0]);
pictureBoxList[ID].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 90);
pictureBoxList[ID].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy";
pictureBoxList[ID].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Enemy;
pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
pictureBoxList[ID].BringToFront();
ID++;
```

**Of course this is assuming the Control.Find return a valid value and not null, but then you would have object reference exception.**

Comment: Yup, I modified so it will find it, but now it gives me the object reference error, I set the name of the current pictureBox before finding it ```pictureBoxList[ID].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy";``` I think I didn't do it right .. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Ricdan then Controls.Find does not return the right value(its null) you probably dont have the right picture box in right container(Controls) maybe even you dont have it at all.Maybe you should loop trough this Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()  and see if there are any that have that name.You need System.Linq for that.

Comment: @Ricdan no you do pictureBoxList[ID].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy"; after you found the picturebox so it is not the error.

Comment: In this control id is pictureBox1 and when i want to add in list i need ID is 1 but first element is added on position is 0 so why pictureBoxList[ID]  we pass same ID variable always get error on first element add. I put answer but got negative but why i dint know

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma yea that might be true i will edit my answer.But there is not need for second variable

Comment: @VukUskokovic yea its up to you if i want to simple things as beginner i just trying give as he/she understand own code not more complex.

Answer (score -2):

Add a guard to the Controls collection so that you do not access elements of the array if they do not exist. That means checking that Controls.Find actually contains items before accessing it with "[0]". I give an example below. Hope it helps you.

```
        private const int MAX_ENEMY = 9;
        private void buttonAddEnemy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ID < MAX_ENEMY)
            {
                Control picBoxControl = Controls.Find("pictureBox" + ID, true)[0];
                if (picBoxControl is PictureBox)
                {
                    pictureBoxList.Add(picBoxControl as PictureBox);
                    //pictureBoxList[ID].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 90);
                    pictureBoxList[ID].Name = "pictureBoxEnemy";
                    pictureBoxList[ID].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
                    pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Enemy;
                    pictureBoxList[ID].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
                    pictureBoxList[ID].BringToFront();
                    ID++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: every time update all properties at position 0. If add another control then you have to do ID++

Comment: The code is to show the use of the guard, i.e. the if condition to check that Controls.Find contains items in its collection. This is what is causing the OutOfBoundsException. You can edit to add additional controls as you wish.